# xamarin forms capture an external application close event in xamarin forms windows 8.1

Tags: c#, pdf, xamarin.forms, windows-8.1

I'm developing a Xamarin forms application for windows 8.1. I'm looking for the solution where i need to capture the closing event for an external application.

eg: i'm opening an pdf in default pdf viewer so, when the user closes the pdf i want to capture that event.

Comment: Are you talking about Windows Phone 8.1? If so I don't think it is possible for one app to monitor another

Comment: No just windows 8.1 desktop version @SteveChadbourne

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a callback when an external application closes unfortunately (as long as you have not implemented the other application and are not sending some HTTP based notification or such). All WinRT apps run in a "silo" so they cannot monitor each other this way.

Comment: Yearly answer review, @RiturajSalavi if this has resolved your issue, please consider accepting the answer as solution so that the question is resolved.